# Jquery Tmpl - Parent objects property from inside an each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a json object with a few properties in it including a list of another object type. I then bind the main object to a template using the tmpl plugin and I have an {{each}} for the list. Inside that each I want to get at a property of the original object.

example:

```
new PageItem(
    'Josie',//Name
    816,//ItemID
    0.0000,//Price
    0,//Quantity
    -1,//DiscountPrice
    'Adopt this bilby!',//Content
    ko.observableArray([ //Mods
        new ModItem(
            '1. Bronze $50', //Name
            812, //ItemID
            50.0000, //Price
                -1//DiscountPrice
        ),
        new ModItem(
            '2. Silver $100', //Name
            813, //ItemID
            100.0000, //Price
                -1//DiscountPrice
        )
    )
```

Template:

```
{{each Mods}}
    ${Name} - ${parentname?}
{{/each}}
```

Probably makes it a bit trickier when the objects have the same property names...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the answer.
using $data (which is the object applied to the template) I can then get the Parent properties from the each loop.

```
{{each Mods}}
    ${Name} - ${$data.Name}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: would you know how this would work if you had a 3rd level 
Section -> Question -> Answer
if you are in answer to get the Id property of the Question object.?

Comment: Not too sure about that... you might need to use a for loop instead of an each in that case.